# Can't move caret/cursor inside textarea in Leaflet map marker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, marker

I have a LeafLet map where I've created a marker consisting of a divIcon with custom html creating a textarea, basically:

```
<textarea placeholder="New text"></textarea">
```

Clicking on the textarea doesn't give it focus so that I can write in it. To fix this I had to add an eventhandler like:

```
$("#mapContainer).on('focus','textarea', mySetFocusFunction);
```

Now the next problem is that I can't position the cursor (or the caret to be precise) in the textarea with the mouse. Clicking on the textarea positions the cursor where I stopped writing last time. Moving the cursor with the keyboard works however. And it also seems to work on my iPad and iPhone...

How can I make it work on my computer as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem thanks to an issue on the Leaflet GIT page:
[Leaflet issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2813)

What I needed was to stop mousedown/move/up events from falling through the textarea. 
This could be done by adding:

```
L.DomEvent.on(textarea, 'mousedown', function(event) {
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(event);
});
L.DomEvent.on(textarea, 'mouseup', function(event) {
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(event);
});
L.DomEvent.on(textarea, 'mousemove', function(event) {
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(event);
});
```

[Example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBKaf)